# Write file with original character using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to write this line into .txt file

```
連携データの取得に失敗しました。
```

This is my code

```
echo 連携データの取得に失敗しました。>>%File_name%
```

And this is result

```
連携デーモﾌ取得に失敗しました。
```

4th and 5th character had change, I have no idea about this. Can someone explain to me what's happen?

Comment: I resolved this.
Control Panel > Region > Change system locale > Japanese